# MonoTouch UISplitViewController - Device and Simulator different

Tags: ipad, xamarin.ios, uisplitviewcontroller, ios5.1

Are there any known issues with `UISplitViewController` in MonoTouch? I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4, MonoTouch 5.2.10 and xCode 4.3.2 (4E2002)

I have a `UISplitViewController`. When I go to portrait I display a button which the user can click to view the 'master' view in a popup controller. On the simulator it works exactly as expected - the master is displayed in a popupviewcontroller.

However, on the device (running iOS5.1), the master view will get pushed in from the side (like it would on a `UINavigationController.PushController()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and this from iOS 5.1 Release Notes:

> In 5.1 the UISplitViewController class adopts the sliding presentation
>   style when presenting the left view (previously only seen in Mail).
>   This style is used when presentation is initiated either by the
>   existing bar button item provided by the delegate methods or by a
>   swipe gesture within the right view. No additional API adoption is
>   required to obtain this behavior, and all existing API, including that
>   of the UIPopoverController instance provided by the delegate, will
>   continue to work as before. If the gesture cannot be supported in your
>   app, set the presentsWithGesture property of your split view
>   controller to NO to disable the gesture. However, disabling the
>   gesture is discouraged because its use preserves a consistent user
>   experience across all applications.

Comment: Which would be ok accept that the master view slides out over the nav bar the button is on and is hiding other buttons I have on the bar. Arghh

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any known issues with UISplitViewController in Monotouch?

Nothing specific to MonoTouch and `UISplitViewController` - but like you found out the later has changed quite a bit internally for iOS 5.1 and this can show up in applications.

> I am using MonoDevelop 2.8.8.4, Monotouch 5.2.10 and xCode 4.3.2 (4E2002)

What's even more important is which version of the iOS simulator are you using ? i.e. iOS 5.0 or iOS 5.1 ?

In any case be aware that different version of iOS calls their selectors at different times. This can lead to cases where the same code will behave differently on different iOS versions.

One known case for this is about `UISplitViewController`. You can [read](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/events-vs-objective-c-delegates/) about it (why and how it can occurs) and how to fix this properly to work identically across both versions of iOS.

**Disclaimer: link to my own blog**

Comment: The iOS simulator is 5.1. Weird.

Comment: It could be something else (similar or totally different). The specific `UISplitViewController` problem I blogged about could be seen using only the simulator (i.e. switching from iOS 5.0 to iOS 5.1)

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is the "new Feature".

There is no Popover(UISplitViewController MasterView) anymore.
I tried to change but nothing works. I asked the Monotouch Support for help. But the also dont know anything.

Here is a Link to my Question maybe this can answer your question better;)

[UISplitViewController problems with IOS 5.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9630492/uisplitviewcontroller-problems-with-ios-5-1)

Comment: and this from iOS 5.1 Release Notes: