# Change the size of MasterViewController when fired as a popover

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

When using a spilt view controller, I have a Master and Detail View. When the iPad is in Portrait mode, the master view is displayed as a popup. How can I adjust the height of the masterview (popup view)?
I have tried:

```
 self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 2 * 52.0);
```

But I am not sure were to set this?

[image]

Comment: I have this same problem and it started when I upgraded to the 5.1 development tools.

Comment: So you think is a bug in the SDK/OS?

Comment: Well, for me it was a change in behavior.  I'm not sure that it is a bug though, and haven't spent a lot of time investigating yet...

Comment: It could certainly depend on SDK version; I'm still on 5.0 with the working example.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that I upgraded from 5.0 to 5.1 and it was working perfectly for me in 5.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used to be able to set the size in viewDidLoad using contentSizeForViewInPopover. But in iOS 5.1, the presentation style of the master view controller was changed to slide in rather than appear as a standard popover. As far as I can tell, it still *is* a UIPopover, but we can no longer modify its size. I tried contentSizeForViewInPopover on the view, as well as setPopoverContentSize on the popover [as suggested on the developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/631201), and neither had any effect.

The [UISplitViewController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISplitViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) doesn't acknowledge this change, nor do the class references for [UIViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIViewController/contentSizeForViewInPopover) or [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html), and the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/AboutViewControllers/AboutViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH112-SW10) still shows the old style of the master view controller popover.

You could try changing the height of the table view inside your detail view, and then [hide the popover's background](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632716/462162). I haven't tried this myself.

Also, since your detail view is showing a map, you might want to [disable the right-swipe gesture that now invokes the master view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9970778/462162), to prevent that from interfering with the map gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen Apple samples use the master view controller's awakeFromNib method and also viewDidLoad.  I'm not sure there's an overriding reason to choose one or the other.

Comment: Odd.  I just tried it in a test split view project and the simple case worked.  (I did see a 'bug' where pushing a new controller into the master area and then returning to the small one set it back to the default size...not sure how to fix that.)